# Way to handle errors in your web application once it has entered production

Tags: web-applications, error-handling

I have reached a point in my web application where we are ready to go live and the thought occurred to me to put in some way of catching application errors users hit and forwarding them on to the appropriate support.

At the moment the site currently catches any errors and redirects to an error page.  It also catches all the data a support person should need to fix the bug.  What we want it to do is provide functionality for the user to send the error details for to a support person somehow.

Ways that we have thought of so far include:

- Simply printing the error on the page as text for the user to copy.
- Providing a button to copy the error onto a clipboard for them to paste into an email.
- Providing a help form for the user to fill in which will send the error on.
- Providing a 'send error' button that simply forwards the error onto an configured or user-entered email address.
- Storing the error details in a database table on page load for a support person to then view.

None of these stand out to me as super clean or intuitive. Has anyone come up with a unique and clean way to handle this kind of situation?

**NB: I am looking for a solution to handle reporting generated errors in the system, not a solution for user feedback.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're displaying all the information the user needs, why not just log it in a database or send an email to support?  That way you don't have to worry the user with the fact that you have bugs.  Send them to your "Sorry, but please try that again later" page...

Comment: Also, users usually hate filling out forms to report bugs. The bug is already annoying enough. Now there's a @#$#@$ form to deal with!

Answer (score 1):

You can try saving the errors to a table in your database, but then you also have to catch the case where the DB is the source of the errors.

What I usually do is to write the error to the Windows error log, along with a unique code (GUID). In the error message the user sees, include the GUID and let them know they can contact your support team if they would like to ask about the error or report more details about what was happening at the time.

To write to the error log, call `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry()`. It's also easy to write tools to query the event log, either programmatically or on the command line with tools like Log Parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at plugging in [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/). It's great for capturing user feedback and easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a unique ID for the error if possible and make sure it is displayed to the user, and logged on the server log.  That way it is easy to tie the error the user is experiencing with what you logged on the back-end.

Remember that it is probably going to be interesting to view the entire set of interactions with that user the lead up to the error, not just the final exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your last comment in bold, I would suggest you use logging of errors.  You do not mention what language you are working in, but if you were using java, you could declare your error pages (eg. `<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>`)and look at what exceptions were handled.  This would work well for expected errors, but may come up short for unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Web developers, we have one easy advantage that fat-client development does not usually have. We have the ability to catch all of our errors from a top level and handle them gracefully.

So we should:

1. Have a way to know automatically when an error occurs

Wouldn't it be great to:

1. Receive an automatic e-mail that contains details of the errors when an error occurs
2. Get descriptive information about the error
3. Know where in your code the error happened
4. Log such information as the user, ip, and all form information
5. Handle multiple applications and Web sites from one error handling page
6. Provide a reference number and a friendly message to users
7. Prevent evil-doers from possibly compromising your Web site.Prevent Crucial Information From Leaking Out

Abscraction with error codes :

```
400      Bad Request
401;1    Unauthorized - Login Failed
401;2    Unauthorized - Login failed due to server configuration
404      Not Found
500      Internal Server Error
500;12   Internal Server Error - Application Restarting
500;13   Internal Server Error - Server Too Busy
500;15   Internal Server Error - Direct Requests For Global.asa
500;100  Internal Server Error - language (ASP,PHP ,JSP) Error
```